# Passing in content to ASP.NET user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl named BreadCrumb.  I would like to pass in information to this user control like so (Similar to DropDownList items):

```
<uc:BreadCrumb runat="server" id="HeaderBreadCrumb">
    <AddLevel Name="Home" Url="~/Default.aspx" />
    <AddLevel Name="About Us" Url="~/AboutUs.aspx" />
</uc:BreadCrumb>
```

Thanks to any help!

Comment: The attribute declarations on ListControl.Items are as follows:`[DefaultValue((string) null), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty), WebCategory("Default"), Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.ListItemsCollectionEditor,System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor)), MergableProperty(false), WebSysDescription("ListControl_Items")]`
Not sure if that helps track down the culprit or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look here [How to: Create an ASP.NET User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc.aspx)  and here [Implementing Custom UserControl with ListItem collection](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2007/03/30/Implementing-Custom-UserControl-with-ListItem-collection.aspx). These approaches doesn't uses templates.

Answer (score -1):

You can support templates, but that's not exactly what you are after.

Take a look at this [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/06/04/Supporting-Templates-with-ASP.NET-User-Controls.aspx) page for more information on using templates on user controls.

Also, take a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx) page on how to create templated user controls.